# Selenium Web Diver, Firefox. Running parallel scraping. Do I need Selenium Grid?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, parallel-processing, web-scraping

I have a process, using Selenium Web driver for Firefox, for automatic look up for information on one specific site. Due to the volume of the data being looked up, I will need to run parallel processes - minimum 10 (I think).
I did a quick test, with 3 processes running in parallel and it seemed ok. But I will need many more..
The Process is written in C#, runs on Windows. Firefox is the only web driver that works with the site.

My questions:

1. Is there any benefit of using the Selenium Grid in my situation?
   Vs just running as many copies of my process (each creating an instance of the selenium web driver) as it is found optimal ?
2. What number of processes (using FF)  may be optimal ? 
   (in terms of FF requests)
   Would FF run parallel requests to the site, or would it queue them ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you would **need** selenium grid is if you are planning to scale this process out across multiple VMs or computers. Otherwise you will only be able to run them all on one machine.

To answer your questions directly

1. Selenium Grid would give you a way to easily scale your automation tasks across multiple machines or VMs. Otherwise you will be restricted to running them only on the machines you have visual studio or if you create an application out of this then you would have to put that application on all the machines you want to use and manually kick it off on them as well (or a task I guess).
2. There is no set optimal number, it depends on your hardware and most importantly your CPU and RAM. I have a 2 node selenium grid setup at work and we run about 5 - 10 tests in parallel at a time on each node. The machines are VMs with quad core i7 CPUs (I believe) and 16 GB RAM. We use chrome though which I believe uses more RAM than Firefox.

Comment: Thank you. What about the max number of concurrent request FF would make (to the same site); I read somewhere it is max 6. Also I wonder whether each instance of selenium driver would create a separate FF process or would it be (as when using the FF manually) just one...

Comment: Hmm I am not sure about the concurrent requests FF could make to one site, I would think that would depend on the site or server thats handles the requests. Every time you initialize a new instance of the WebDriver it does create a new process with its own PID so each instance would be totally separate from the other ones.

Comment: No problem! Please make the answer as accepted if I've answered your question.